# Procedure error "Must declare the table"

Tags: sql, procedure

I have a block code to create a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetTableinfomation
    @table nvarchar(50),
    @column nvarchar(50), 
    @valuedk nvarchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN 
   SELECT *  
   FROM @table 
   WHERE @column = @valuedk 
END
```

and I have an error.

> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure GetTableinfomation, Line 7
>   Must declare the table variable "@tenbang".

Why?

Comment: As implied by another answer `SELECT * FROM @table` assumes you've created a table variable with `DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, etc VARCHAR(16))`.  You need to build a new SQL string and call `EXEC` or *(preferably)* `sp_executesql` with that new string.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use SQL parameters for table names and columns, only for variables.

You could get around this by using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @PARAMS nvarchar(4000)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' 
    + QUOTENAME(@table,'"') + ' WHERE ' 
    + QUOTENAME(@column,'"') + '= @param1'
SET @PARAMS = '@param1 nvarchar(50)'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @PARAMS, @param1=@valuedk
```

See the documentation on `sp_executesql` for more information:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: `sp_executesql` is usually preferable to `exec` : plan caching, parameterisation, etc.